# Will this scoped service be available and cleared correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm using signalr core.

```
class MyHub: Hub 
{
    IScopedService _scoped;

    void Test() 
    {
        _scoped.Test();
    }
}

class ScopedService: IScopedService 
{
    ISingletonService _singleton;
    IAnotherService _another;

    public void Test() 
    {
        _singleton.Fire(() => OnEnd());
    }

    public void OnEnd() 
    {
        // _anotherService calls
    }
}

class SingletonService: ISingletonService
{
    private Action _action

    public void Fire(Action action)
    {
        _action = action;
        Start();
    }

    private void Start() 
    {
        // starts a task that after some time calls _action 
    }
}
```

My question is can i expect `IScopedService` and it's dependencies be still available for a delegate call after some time (let's say 30 seconds) even though it ran out of scope (i guess so, due to delegate reference), and to be properly garbage collected when i do `_action = null` in `SingletonService`

Comment: I believe that dependencies in singleton services will be kept along with the singleton instance. Otherwise the singleton instance will be useless for its purpose (which should live in a long time to serve the other services).

Comment: ASP.NET Core scoped services are instantiated when a request starts and disposed when the request finishes. What will happen depends on the (now invisible) implementation of ScopedService and its dependencies

Comment: Because the `Action` references the `OnEnd` instance method of `ScopedService`, it will capture a reference to that `ScopedService`. This means that `SingletonService` will hold a reference to `ScopedService` (through the `Action`). `ScopedService` thereby became a [Captive Dependency](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/).